# Windowed read of a raster producing wrong projection?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, rasterio

I'm using `rasterio` to read in a `.tif` file and converting it to vectors using the [`rasterio.features`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/topics/features.rst) module. For a particularly large `.tif` file, I thought I'd use the [windowed read](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/topics/windowed-rw.rst) option, but for some reason the projections are coming way off when doing the windowed read. Notice how the Y coordinates are very different between the two outputs but the X coordinates are similar. Any ideas on why this is happening? See the example below:

#### With windowed read

`with rasterio.open('raster2vector/clipped_fire2_reprojected.tif') as dataset:
    for block_index, window in dataset.block_windows(1):
        mask = dataset.read_masks(1, window=window)
        image = dataset.read(1, window=window)
        results = (
            {'properties': {'pixel_value': v}, 'geometry': s}
            for i, (s, v) 
            in enumerate(
                shapes(image=image, mask=mask, transform=dataset.transform)))
        geoms = list(results)
        if not geoms:
            continue
        print(dataset.crs)
        print(geoms[0])
        break`

produces

`CRS({'init': 'epsg:2163'})
{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[(-1861517.9955081018, 916182.1706994411),
    (-1861517.9955081018, 915914.427799729),
    (-1860447.0239092538, 915914.427799729),
    (-1860447.0239092538, 916182.1706994411),
    (-1861517.9955081018, 916182.1706994411)]],
  'type': 'Polygon'},
 'properties': {'pixel_value': 6.0}}`

#### Without windowed read

`with rasterio.open('raster2vector/clipped_fire2_reprojected.tif') as dataset:
    mask = dataset.read_masks(1)
    image = dataset.read(1)
    results = (
        {'properties': {'pixel_value': v}, 'geometry': s}
        for i, (s, v) 
        in enumerate(
            shapes(image=image, mask=mask, transform=dataset.transform)))
    print(dataset.crs)
    geoms = list(results)
    print(geoms[0])`

produces

`CRS({'init': 'epsg:2163'})
{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[(-1861517.9955081018, -457874.39062262117),
    (-1861517.9955081018, -458409.87642204505),
    (-1861250.2526083898, -458409.87642204505),
    (-1861250.2526083898, -458142.1335223331),
    (-1860982.509708678, -458142.1335223331),
    (-1860982.509708678, -458409.87642204505),
    (-1860714.7668089657, -458409.87642204505),
    (-1860447.0239092538, -458409.87642204505),
    (-1860447.0239092538, -457874.39062262117),
    (-1861517.9955081018, -457874.39062262117)]],
  'type': 'Polygon'},
 'properties': {'pixel_value': 6.0}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the transform object needs to actually be

`transform = rasterio.windows.transform(window, dataset.transform)`

for windowed reads.